# Umbraco 5 newb: Content from custom Table

Tags: umbraco5

I am currently investigating the possibilities of different CMSs for a company-site.
Done quite a few projects in classical ASP, ASP.NET, Joomla etc..

I would like to use Umbraco 5 for the first time.

For that project we have a SQL-Table with Job-Opportunities: 
like: JobName, Department, Description, etc..
These should be listed on a page. In ASP.NET I would use something like a Repeater, etc.. with PageSize option and automatic paging.
In the Backend (Backoffice in Umbraco, I assume) there has to be an Insert/Edit/Delete  Page with the corresponding input boxes, which are maintained by the company employees, not by web-developers.

Which route should I look at? I am completely stuck, is there an example anywhere?
Can I use my own data-tables, or could/should I use the Umbraco content tables for this?

Thank you,
Reinhard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to Umbraco.

If you choose to use a pre-existing database, you're going to need the following pieces:

1. an ORM to access read/write the data
2. a custom hive provider for that data to allow for Umbrace to read it as an entity
3. a custom tree to allow for editing and adding data in the backoffice
4. a macro to display the content on the frontend.

http://web-matters.blogspot.com/2011/11/umbraco-5-hive-provider-tree-editor.html
is a great place to start.

As you're probably picking up on, this is a lot of work.. so, most importantly: Are you trying to maintain two applications?

If so, do you really need to be able to edit the list in *both* applications? Your task would be much simpler if you only allowed editing from the other application, and displayed the read-only list using web services.

If not, ditch the custom database. Umbraco 5 is a full EAV/CR system, so unlike some CMS products, you'll be able to represent any rdbs structure you can imagine. The simplest way would be to create a custom document type with those properties to represent a job opportunity, and store those job opportunities on a new node in the content tab.

About document types: http://our.umbraco.org/wiki/how-tos/working-with-document-types